# Best way to define a fitness function which can be optimized by GA making multiple properties be close to specified values

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

Recently, I met such a questions, which require to optimize multiple properties of a designed material make them close to specified values.

For example, I have 3 reference property values (**pv** for short) values (i.e., pv01_ref = 10.2, pv02_ref = 200, pv03_ref = -0.5). These **pv** values can be calculated for the research **material**.

Now, what I want to do is: designed a **material**, making it have **pv** values closed to the reference ones as above.

I can think about this issue as the multiple-parameter optimization problem, which should be able to be solved by the genetic algorithm (**GA**) (or related heuristic methods).

Suppose that I plan to use **GA** to solve this task. Now **GA** need optimize the fitness function (a scalar function), where trying to make the fitness the larger, the better (i.e., **GA** should try to obtain the maximum value of the fitness function from the material).

I tried to propose such a fitness function as below.

```
J(m) = 1/abs(10.2 - pv01) + 1/abs(200 - pv02) + 1/abs(-0.5 - pv03)
```

In this fitness function, I want to make the pv01, pv02 and pv03 from the new designed material having values as closer to the reference ones as possible (i.e., 10.2, 200, -0.5). If so, the fitness value should be maximized by **GA**.

But I am not sure if this is a good defined fitness function, can you give me some suggestions about how to define such multiple-parameter optimization fitness function, making **GA** optimize/maximize it more reasonable?

Thanks.

Comment: your fitness function should depend on material parameters from which then you would  first calculate `pv` values within fitness function. You could use inverse of l1 (or l2, or infinity but infinity norm could cause premature convergence more easily) norm for fitness function: `1/sum(abs(material_p - target_p))`.

Comment: @det Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to your solutions.